# Laravel Composer Update Changed Files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, composer-php

I need to discus a very important thing for me (probably for all users who uses composer in their projects). I am working on laravel. Whenever i work on my local machine, i run composer update after adding new library in vendor.

Now it works fine on local machine. But when i upload these files on my server, it shoots error like "Undefine class ....". I dont know how to run composer update command on server (Also it might be not safe).

So may i just know which files are updated by using `composer update` on cmd. What other files needed to go live to avoid this error??

Comment: You should not run `composer update` on your server. When you run `composer update` in your development environment it will create a `composer.lock` file which contains all of your package version information. That file should be committed into version control and should become available on your server. At this point, you should run `composer install` on your server to ensure that you pull down the dependencies that worked on your development environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may:

- Run `composer update` on your **local** server only, whenever you want.
- Commit/push every files (including `composer.lock`) **but the `vendor` directory**
- Deliver to your production server (without `vendor`, with `composer.lock`)
- Then run `composer install` on your production server. It will update all your dependencies according to your `composer.lock`(so the **exact** same versions as your last update on your local server).

So in other words: you should not run `composer update` on your server, just `composer install` on every delivery (and you will need to keep your `composer.lock`)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But what should we do if the server is a shared hosting which doesn't allow us to run any composer command?

Comment: Send `vendor\package` folder to your hosting

Answer (score 2):

run `composer dump-autoload` before `composer update`. If still doesn't work then try to clear composer cache using `composer clear-cache`

Comment: This ignores the OP's good observation that "it might be not safe to run `composer update` on server". It's _not_ safe to run that command on the server. Commit `composer.lock` and run `composer install` instead of `composer update`. (In many cases this applies to development machines, too.) That's the whole reason that file and command exist.

Answer (score 2):

`composer update` will update the version of every package from you vendor folder.

normally if you can not ensure you need update all the version of every package, you should use `composer install`

the reason of error "undefined class" is normally caused from app.php.Because service provider is defined in app.php, but the class(package) not been installed.

in order to solve your problem, try do this in three ways:

1. composer install --no-scripts;
2. comment the service providers which not been installed already from     app.php, then composer install
3. composer dump-autoload